# How to remove Duplicates in .txt file

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a .txt file with the below entries:-

```
Apples  51824
Oranges  131236
Peaches  6564
Apples  5879
Peaches 69878
```

I am trying to remove the entire row (**when duplicate entries are found**) from this file whenever a word (say Apples) matches in that row (keeping in mind that the entry with the highest value **stays**).

What I presently do:-

```
1. Open the file in Excel.
2. Go to Data --> Remove Duplicates
```

The issue with this approach according to me is that I am not sure whether the end result gives me the data with highest values all the time or not.

So, How can it be programmatically (**in python, preferably**) done?

Comment: Are the entries comma separated in the source file?

Comment: No, it is separated by a  **tab**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 solutions one in Python and another in Nodejs without using third party libraries:

Python:

```
import re
import json

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read()

lines = lines.split('\n')
fruit = {}

for line in lines:
    key, value = re.split(r'\s{4}', line)
    if (key not in fruit or int(fruit[key]) < int(value)):
        fruit[key] = value


fruit = json.dumps(fruit)
fruit = re.sub(r'["{}:]', '', fruit)
fruit = re.sub(r', ', '\n', fruit)

with open('fruits.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(fruit)
```

Nodejs:

```
import fs from 'fs'

const file = fs.readFileSync('data.txt', 'utf8');
const lines = file.split('\n');
let fruit = {}

for (const line of lines) {
    const [key, value] = line.split(/\s{4}/)
    !fruit[key] || +fruit[key] < +value ? fruit[key] = value : null
}

fruit = JSON.stringify(fruit)
    .replace(/["{}]/g, '')
    .replace(/:/g, ' ')
    .replace(/,/g, '\n')

fs.writeFileSync('fruits.txt', fruit)
```

Comment: i ran the first solution (in python). Unfortunately, it is giving the error - ```(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError("invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'BY'"), <traceback object at 0x0000025DDD534E80>)```. The entry where it threw error was - ```'BETTER BY ZAYN 594884' ```. I believe it goes into error whenever the entry has **spaces** in between them (**prior to the numbers**). any workaround?

Comment: this is the url for the debug screenshot - [https://github.com/atulk93/Python-Related/blob/master/removing_duplicates_debug.PNG]

Comment: Are they always separated by tab?

Comment: yes. the numbers are always separated by tab. Not the strings. They have spaces whenever there is more than one word.

Comment: I update the code try it, check number of spaces between the word and number and change this number according to that `r'\s{4}'`

Answer (score 0):

That would probably work

```py
from collections import defaultdict

filename1 = ""
filename2 = ""

words = defaultdict(int)
with open(filename1) as f1:
    for line in f1:
        word, value = line.strip().split() 
        if int(value) > words[word]:
            words[word] = int(value) 

with open(filename2, "w") as f2:
    for line in words.items():
        f2.write(line)
```

If you have pandas data frame then:

```py
import pandas 
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
result = df.groupby('Name').agg({'values': 'max'}) 
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive way is to use dictionaries:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

my_dict = {};
for line in lines:
    s_line = line.split()
    if s_line[0] in my_dict and my_dict[s_line[0]] < int(s_line[1]):
        my_dict[s_line[0]] = int(s_line[1])
    else:
        my_dict[s_line[0]] = int(s_line[1])

new_f = open('test_no_duplicates.txt', 'w')
for key in my_dict:
    new_f.write(key + " " + str(my_dict[key]) + "\n")

f.close()
new_f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

textFile = Path("./sample1.txt")

text = textFile.read_text()

rows = text.split("\n")
entries = [x.split("  ") for x in rows]

data = { 
    "Fruits": [x[0] for x in entries],
    "Values": [x[1] for x in entries]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = df.groupby(["Fruits"]).max()

new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

np.savetxt("./out.txt", new_df.values, fmt='%s')
```

#### Example:

sample1.txt

```
Apples  51824
Oranges  131236
Peaches  6564
Apples  5879
Peaches  69878
```

out.txt

```
Apples 5879
Oranges 131236
Peaches 69878
```

Comment: If you dont have pandas installed you can do it by running `pip install pandas` in your cmd

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution in just a few lines, and outputs a nice and flat CSV file.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('apples.txt') as f:
    text = [[i, int(j)] for i, j in [i.strip().split() for i in f.readlines()]]

(pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['fruit', 'count'])
 .groupby('fruit')
 .agg({'count': 'max'})
 .reset_index()
 .to_csv('apples_out.txt', index=False))
```

Output:

```
fruit,count
Apples,51824
Oranges,131236
Peaches,69878
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary to remember best value/line pair for each fruit:

```
results = {}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fruit, value = line.split()
        value = int(value)
        if fruit not in results or results[fruit][0] < value:
            results[fruit] = (value, line.strip())

print('\n'.join(item[1] for item in results.values()))
```